# NextJS Access to variable from another component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a variable in a component. And I want the value of the variable returned by the function SetScore()

btnRotate.jsx

```js
setScoreState((prevS) => {
                  if (btn.deg == deg) {
                    
  
                    //console.log(prevS);
                    return prevS + 1;
                  } else {
                    
                    //console.log(prevS);
                    return prevS;
                  }
     });
```

I want to use the value of the variable prevS here

Img.jsx

```js
function Img({ i, lengthArr }) {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const [score1, setScore1] = useState(0);
  const [score2, setScore2] = useState(0);
  ///
  const [scoreState, setScoreState] = useState(1);
  //console.log(prevS);
  
 ...
```

Comment: General idea is to pass variable/function as a props to child element. Or use global state with `redux` or `context`. And can't really comment on this without proper file structure

Comment: The returned value from the function called inside `setScoreState` will be available in `scoreState`. You can simply use that variable instead, i.e. `console.log(scoreState);` - that's exactly the point of using state variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to keep previous state values

```
import { useRef, useState } from 'react'

function Img({ i, lengthArr }) {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const [score1, setScore1] = useState(0);
  const [score2, setScore2] = useState(0);
  const [scoreState, setScoreState] = useState(1);
  const scoreStateRef = useRef(1); //add `useRef`
  
  console.log(scoreStateRef.current); //replace for `prevS`
  
 ...
```

Here is how to set values for `scoreStateRef`

```
setScoreState((prevS) => {
  scoreStateRef.current = prevS; //set value here
  if (btn.deg == deg) {
    //console.log(prevS);
    return prevS + 1;
  } else {
    //console.log(prevS);
    return prevS;
  }
});
```